# how to extract Country value from the Map

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    void main(){
  var map = {
    "Countries":[{"ID":"334d3cba-c305-4bd6-8da1-97bdc8273eec",
      "Country":"Afghanistan",
      "CountryCode":"AF",
      "Slug":"afghanistan",
      "NewConfirmed":0,
      "TotalConfirmed":161290,
      "NewDeaths":0,
      "TotalDeaths":7405,
      "NewRecovered":0,
      "TotalRecovered":0,
      "Date":"2022-01-30T07:14:34.603Z","Premium":{}}]};
  
}
```

Comment: Well? You have a map, and "Country" is the key. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: [TutorialsPoint: Dart Maps](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_map.htm)

Comment: map['Countries']![index]['Country']

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```dart
void main(){
  var map = {
    "Countries":[{"ID":"334d3cba-c305-4bd6-8da1-97bdc8273eec",
      "Country":"Afghanistan",
      "CountryCode":"AF",
      "Slug":"afghanistan",
      "NewConfirmed":0,
      "TotalConfirmed":161290,
      "NewDeaths":0,
      "TotalDeaths":7405,
      "NewRecovered":0,
      "TotalRecovered":0,
      "Date":"2022-01-30T07:14:34.603Z","Premium":{}}],};
  print((map['Countries'] as List)[0]['Country']);
}
```